# Why data.table rbindlist() argument use.names = TRUE is not working when segmenting data?

Tags: r, data.table

Given the data structure below:

```
DT1 = data.table(value=c(1,2,3,4),descA = "AA")
DT2 = data.table(value=c(3,4,5,6),descB = "BB")
l = list(DT1,DT2)
cat <- c("G", "M")
ldt <- data.table(l, cat)
```

Note that the name of the description columns varies for each dataset (`LA`,`LB`).
The goal is to 'unnest' the data, keeping the original description columns and recycling for the category `cat`.

I tried:

```
ldt[, rbindlist(l, fill = T, use.names = T), by = cat]
```

which output is:

```
   cat value descA
1:   G     1    AA
2:   G     2    AA
3:   G     3    AA
4:   G     4    AA
5:   M     3    BB
6:   M     4    BB
7:   M     5    BB
8:   M     6    BB
```

However, rbindlist in this implementation is ignoring use.names = TRUE and fill = TRUE, and does not give the desired output:

```
   cat value descA descB
1:   G     1    AA    NA 
2:   G     2    AA    NA    
3:   G     3    AA    NA
4:   G     4    AA    NA
5:   M     3    NA    BB
6:   M     4    NA    BB
7:   M     5    NA    BB
8:   M     6    NA    BB
```

How do I get the desired output? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
ldt[, l[[1L]][, cat := cat], cat]
rbindlist(ldt$l, use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

output:

```
   value descA cat descB
1:     1    AA   G  <NA>
2:     2    AA   G  <NA>
3:     3    AA   G  <NA>
4:     4    AA   G  <NA>
5:     3  <NA>   M    BB
6:     4  <NA>   M    BB
7:     5  <NA>   M    BB
8:     6  <NA>   M    BB
```

Comment: but its missing the cat column